# C# DateTime.Now in Azure not reporting GMT - can the default timezone be set?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

In azure websites the DateTime.Now always gives back the time in UTC, where I need to be able to set the timezone to GMT, so all times are currently an hour out.

I'm **not** able to change any of the code at this point, so the question is whether the default timezone can be changed either in configuration or programatically (it's possible to set the default culture in Global.asax to ensure date formats are correct).

Comment: GMT is essentially the same as UTC and [has no offset](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/gmt). You are confusing it with BST or IST perhaps? In any case you should *not* make any dependencies on specific timezones and use DateTimeOffset if the timezone has significance for you.

Comment: Yes sorry, I did mean BST - sometimes it's hard to remember it's actually summer!!  DateTimeOffset is the ideal for sure, I've just got a legacy codebase here which I can't alter easily

Comment: Not sure but try in webrole. So instantiating webrole should have culture set

Comment: @MaheshMalpani changing the timezone of a web role is [unreliable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/07/29/manage-timezone-for-applications-on-windows-azure.aspx). In any case, the OP is using Web Sites for which there *is* a reliable way to change the timezone

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, GMT is essentially the same as UTC - [it has no offset](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/gmt). To be precise, UTC [supersedes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) GMT .  You are probably confusing it with BST which is GMT+1:00 during summer time.

In general, it's a bad idea to make assumptions about timezones, especially in web applications. Instead of DateTime you should use DateTimeOffset.

Luckily, there was a recent change for Azure Web Sites and now you *can* [change the timezone of an Azure Web site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2015/04/07/changing-the-server-time-zone-on-azure-web-apps.aspx) in a supported and reliable way. From the MSDN blog post

> All you need to do is add an [Application Setting](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/) (via the portal or the management APIs) called WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE and set that to the name of the time zone as defined in the Windows Registry under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Nt\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\ (for example, “AUS Eastern Standard Time”).

Unfortunately, Windows mixes up the timezones and uses the name "GMT Standard Time" to refer to BST and "UTC" to refer to GMT/UTC.

Comment: Hurrah!  As a reference for anyone else looking for GMT/BST, the value for WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE is "GMT Standard Time"

Comment: @Paul almost - as I said GMT isn't BST but there is *no* BST* in Windows and "GMT Standard Time" is used as if it were "British Standard Time". The real GMT is called "UTC"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is convenient that the setting accurately reflects local (London) time. As opposed to explicitly setting DST, and then having to manually revert back to GMT when the clocks change. Personally, I prefer this. Although for certain requirements, granted it maybe not suitable...

Comment: @Phil that's actually wrong. You have to convert offsets if you *assume* a specific local time offset. If you want to store any future time you'll actually have to take into account DST before generating a "local" time too. Storing *past* dates will require storing an offset too, if you care about correct interval calculations. A DateTimeOffset though needs no conversion at all. It *doesn't* change due to DST. If you want to avoid changes even if the UK abandons DST though, you should use the IANA timezone names instead of offsets, and a library like NodaTime.

Comment: @Phil btw airlines post flight times *and* offsets precisely because they need no conversion. They can't have ambiguities around departure times that fall *on* the DST change hour either. You see local times because the  web sites of airlines, OTAs convert them to local times. BTW OTAs (online travel agencies) add different fees for long flights too, which is why they can't work with local time

Comment: Very interesting. I don't have any specific knowledge of airline industry, but thanks for the share. :)